# Execute Spark sql query within withColumn clause is Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has one of the column called "Query" having the select statement present. Want to execute this query and create a new column having actual results from the TempView.

```
+--------------+-----------+-----+----------------------------------------+
|DIFFCOLUMNNAME|DATATYPE   |ISSUE|QUERY                                   |
+--------------+-----------+-----+----------------------------------------+
|Firstname     |StringType |YES  |Select Firstname from TempView  limit 1 |
|LastName      |StringType |NO   |Select LastName from TempView  limit 1  |
|Designation   |StringType |YES  |Select Designation from TempView limit 1|
|Salary        |IntegerType|YES  |Select Salary from TempView    limit 1  |
+--------------+-----------+-----+----------------------------------------+
```

Getting error as Type mismatch, Required String found column.
Do I need to use UDF here. But not sure how to write and use. Please suggest

```
DF.withColumn("QueryResult", spark.sql(col("QUERY")))
```

TempView is Temporary View which I have created having all the required columns.
Expected final Dataframe will be something like this with the new column added QUERYRESULT.

```
+--------------+-----------+-----+----------------------------------------+------------+
|DIFFCOLUMNNAME|DATATYPE   |ISSUE|QUERY                                   | QUERY RESULT
+--------------+-----------+-----+----------------------------------------+------------+
|Firstname     |StringType |YES  |Select Firstname from TempView  limit 1 | Bunny      |
|LastName      |StringType |NO   |Select LastName from TempView  limit 1  | Gummy      |
|Designation   |StringType |YES  |Select Designation from TempView limit 1| Developer  |
|Salary        |IntegerType|YES  |Select Salary from TempView    limit 1  | 100        |
+--------------+-----------+-----+----------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: show some code for others to look at. unusual construct

Comment: I added the code, The one line having withColumn clause. Getting error since expected is String and getting column

Comment: The short answer is "no, you cannot do that". What you can do is a work-around illustrated in pasha701s answer: collect the queries so that they are available in the driver and then execute the queries one by one. But why would you store the queries in a Spark dataframe at all when the data needs to be present in the driver process anyway? It would probably be easier to use a list of case classes instead of a Spark dataframe to hold the queries.

Answer (score 3):

If number of queries is limited, you can collect them, execute each, and join with original queries dataframe (Kieran was faster with his answer, but mine answer has example):

```
val queriesDF = Seq(
  ("Firstname", "StringType", "YES", "Select Firstname from TempView  limit 1 "),
  ("LastName", "StringType", "NO", "Select LastName from TempView  limit 1 "),
  ("Designation", "StringType", "YES", "Select Designation from TempView limit 1"),
  ("Salary", "IntegerType", "YES", "Select Salary from TempView limit 1 ")
).toDF(
  "DIFFCOLUMNNAME", "DATATYPE", "ISSUE", "QUERY"
)
val data = Seq(
  ("Bunny", "Gummy", "Developer", 100)
)
  .toDF("Firstname", "LastName", "Designation", "Salary")

data.createOrReplaceTempView("TempView")

// get all queries and evaluate results
val queries = queriesDF.select("QUERY").distinct().as(Encoders.STRING).collect().toSeq
val queryResults = queries.map(q => (q, spark.sql(q).as(Encoders.STRING).first()))
val queryResultsDF = queryResults.toDF("QUERY", "QUERY RESULT")

// Join original queries and results
queriesDF.alias("queriesDF")
  .join(queryResultsDF, Seq("QUERY"))
  .select("queriesDF.*", "QUERY RESULT")
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+-----+------------+
|QUERY                                   |DIFFCOLUMNNAME|DATATYPE   |ISSUE|QUERY RESULT|
+----------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+-----+------------+
|Select Firstname from TempView  limit 1 |Firstname     |StringType |YES  |Bunny       |
|Select LastName from TempView  limit 1  |LastName      |StringType |NO   |Gummy       |
|Select Designation from TempView limit 1|Designation   |StringType |YES  |Developer   |
|Select Salary from TempView limit 1     |Salary        |IntegerType|YES  |100         |
+----------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+-----+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have that many 'query rows', just collect the results to driver using df.collect() and then map over queries using plain Scala.

Comment: That's not an answer to this actual question. It's an alternative - possibly.

Comment: Sure, its not the answer to the current wording, but it answers the intent of their question...

Comment: They tend to be finnicky here, so so am I for once.

Comment: Then edit the question and be more specific. Given the question they could need a little more info.

Comment: The first line of their question is "I have a dataframe which has one of the column called "Query" having the select statement present. Want to execute this query and create a new column having actual results from the TempView."

Comment: Yes, that shows the intent of what they are trying to achieve.