# Column is not iterable when passing a column in an expr function

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with two columns.

```
data = [(
"AAA BBB CCC DDD", 
"CASE WHEN  categories NOT LIKE '%EEE%' OR (categories NOT LIKE '%CCC%' AND categories NOT LIKE '%EEE%') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END"),
]

schema = ["categories", "sql"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
```

I'm trying to evaluate the categories column with the sql in the sql column.

```
df_result = df.withColumn("pass", expr(col("sql")))
```

But I'm running into an exception:

> Column is not iterable

Any suggestions, or even a different approach?

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176238/execute-spark-sql-query-within-withcolumn-clause-is-spark-scala

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but hope it gives some new idea. You can not iterate over a dataframe unless you convert on a RDD and work with a list.

```
df_source = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     (1, 'AAA BBB CCC DDD')
    ,(2, 'AAA BBB WWW ZZZ')
    ,(3, 'EEE BBB WWW ZZZ')
    ,(4, 'AAA EEE YYY DDD')
  ], ['id', 'categories']
)
                                           
lst_Conditions = [
    ('Cond_1', 'CASE WHEN  categories NOT LIKE "%EEE%" OR (categories NOT LIKE "%CCC%" AND categories NOT LIKE "%EEE%") THEN "1" ELSE "0" END'),
    ('Cond_2', 'CASE WHEN  categories NOT LIKE "%ZZZ%" OR (categories NOT LIKE "%WWW%" AND categories NOT LIKE "%ZZZ%") THEN "1" ELSE "0" END')
]

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

for c in lst_Conditions:
  df_source = df_source.withColumn(c[0], F.expr(c[1]))
  
df_source = df_source.withColumn('pass', F.coalesce(df_source['Cond_1'], df_source['Cond_2']))

df_source.show()
```